# How to use AutoSizing Property from xib + iPhone

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, xib

I want to know how to use autosizing property in interface builder i.e. how this property can be used in autoadjustment of subview height , width and their position in superview.

Thanx,

Regards

tek3

Answer (score 2):

The use of the autosizing function only really applies in iOS when you are rotating views. So for instance:

1. select an object in the view, say, a button
2. in the "Autosizing" section of the "Button Size" pane of the Inspector palette: activate the red "internal" arrows by clicking on them.
3. Now click the "autorotate" button in the upper right of the title bar for the View window.

notice how the button now scales and stretches. Now experiment with activating and de-activating different "springs and struts" in the Autosizing inspector area, and continue to click the auto-rotate button to toggle between portrait and landscape views.

You'll soon have an intuitive understanding of how these controls effect the relative layout of your app.